# name and the path of the file to edit the related product prices in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have to change the price in the related product, the products which are showing at the bottom of the single-product page in the front end.

Actually, I have to change the price of only related products. I tried hard to find out this file in the woo-commerce I find out the related-products.php but there a template called single-product.

Actually, I don't found anywhere price file for the related products.

I want the path name to edit this file. Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The product price should be changed in the database. you need to login in to admin of the website and can change the price of the product.

Comment: Related Product price means i don't want to show the original price there instead in the backend i had used the custom field, just i have to show up that custom field value in place of related products price.